# How to add a default predefined thumbnail when creating a brand new post?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, post-thumbnails, attachments

I'm making a plugin that has a custom post type and I need to add predefined content.

I used filters `default_title` and `default_content` for the title and content but I can't find how I can add an predefined attachment (thumbnail) image.

In my plugin I have the settings option where I set the default image and there I have the attachment ID. Now all I have to do is set it up when I create a new post.

Is there any action or filter to I can use it?

Comment: Do you need the default thumbnail to be saved to the post, or do you just want to display a default image on the front end if the post doesn't have a thumbnail?

Comment: I need default thumbnail to be saved to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an adequate solution.

Generally, I used the `save_post_{$post->post_type}` hook which gave me a `$post_ID` and a `$post` object.

I was just checking to see if there was a thumbnail and if is not there to add it. That is all.

```
add_action( 'save_post_book', function ($post_ID, $post){
    if ( get_post_meta($post_ID, '_thumbnail_id', true) ) :
        return;
    endif;
    
    if($thumbnail_id = get_option('my_default_thumbnail_id', false)) {
        add_post_meta($post_ID, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id);
    }
}, 10, 2);
```